# Mac .dmg backup, files disappeared?

Tags: mac, backup, ssd, recovery, dmg

I was having some issues with my Mac so I booted into recovery mode and made an image of my internal SSD drive to a .dmg compressed format and then saved it to my external SSD.
Then I erased the Mac and did a clean install of Mac OS.

The issue is now when I'm opening up the Mac dmg backup I can't find any of my files even though it says it is 112gb disk image. Is the 112gb just empty space?
When I mount the .dmg It opens three folders; VM, recovery and preboot and these are only have around 1gb of data in each.

Where are the other 100 GB worth of files? Maybe I have done something wrong. I just want to know what is going on.

EDIT -
I have managed to find my files the drive was in APFS format so I downloaded EaseUs data recovery, after trying loads of software this one deals with APFS. Thanks goodness I didn't delete my files.

Comment: Did you not visually verify the contents of the DMG before erasing the drive?

Comment: I couldn't because I only have one Macbook, and the SSD is formatted to work on apple PC's. I have no idea what files are in there if any. Is it possible it's 112gb of nothing? I mean I thought it must have my files in it because that's how much GBs my files were taking up.

Comment: This doesn‘t seem to be a DMG but rather a full disk image, so your data may still be in there somewhere. How exactly did you create it?

Comment: Basically I went into recovery mode holding down command and R when booting then I went into disk utility and the file and then new image from and chose my SSD. It took around 1 hour (which I thought was pretty short tbh) then I reinstalled my Mac. then I couldn't find my files when loading the DMG, perhaps its some sort of empty space but I'm not sure if that's possible. I have bought a new USB stick 128gbs and now I'm trying to convert the file to read and write on my usb, but i'm not sure if that will do anything at all.

Comment: You could have opened and examined the DMG from Disk Utility directly after creating it while in Recovery. There is no need to convert it as you should be able to just open/mount it and see your files.

Comment: Ahh so Im guessing something must have went wrong. Do you think I should delete the backup or is there anything else I can do?

Comment: If you have thoroughly examined the contents of the DMG and it does not contain your files then it's of no use, but without seeing it I'm not going to tell you to delete it, especially if that's the only backup you have.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm just wondering what could the other 100gbs be made of if not my files? Could it be like a partition of empty space maybe.

Comment: Can you open the DMG and post a screenshot of the Disk Utility window with the DMG selected?

Comment: I don't think I can, it doesn't mount the Data part only the three other parts VM, Recovery and Preboot. I can't seem to find the data part of the DMG

Comment: With the DMG mounted, what is the output of `diskutil list` in Terminal?

Comment: I have added some images - https://imgur.com/a/TulINb2

Comment: #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +121.1 GB   disk5
                                 Physical Store disk4
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     99.5 GB    disk5s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 82.5 MB    disk5s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.1 MB   disk5s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk5s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.1 GB

Comment: The data part doesn't mount though, is that because my Mac only has 128gb of storage internal?

Comment: Well maybe it does mount if it is showing up in terminal, but I can't find it in finder or disk utility ???

Comment: Ahh it says Uninitialised in disk utility, can that be fixed?